# Sitecore Azure WebApp and TLS 1.2

Tags: security, azure, reporting

I want to use the most secure TLS 1.2 on Sitecore Azure Web apps for all 4 roles - CD, CM, PRC and REP.
I did not do any changes in Analytics processing and reporting - so, I do not deploy my code to PRC and REP roles anymore.
Will it still work if I enable TLS 1.2 for all 4 web apps or I need to deploy some code there as well to alter ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol?

Answer (score 1):

I tested it - and it works (I see visits in Analytics reports). So, I came to conclusion that it is possible to enable TLS 1.2 connections only on Sitecore web apps